# JavaFX textArea.setText not working in loop

Tags: javafx, textarea

I have a function named doWrite, which is basically representing the action of a button.
In this function, inside the for loop, txtShow.setText(st.toString()) is not showing any data on GUI, but the same thing is visible on console using System.out.println,
I have also used txtShow.setText at the end of the function to print "block written successfully" but this is displayed on GUI successfully.
I want to know why it is not working in for loop.

Part of Controller code:

```
 @FXML
    void doWrite(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //txtShow.setText("Scan your card");
        OutputStream os=s1.getOutputStream();
        String messageString ="%"+txtBlock.getText()+txtData.getText(); 
        os.write(messageString.getBytes());
        //System.out.println(messageString);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    InputStream is=s1.getInputStream();

    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();


        for(int i=0,x=0;true;i++){
        char a=(char)is.read();
        if(a == '@'){

            txtShow.setText(st.toString());
            System.out.print(st.toString());
         st.setLength(0);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            continue;
        }
        if(a == '*')
        {
            break;
        }

        st=st.append(a);
    }
    System.out.print( st.toString());
    txtShow.setText("Block written successfully");
    //doAlert("Block written successfully !");

}
```

Main code:

```
package Cards;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class cardMain extends Application {
    //static boolean x=true;



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("card.fxml")); 
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.setFill(Color.NAVY);  
            primaryStage.setTitle("Student Registration"); 
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{


         launch(args);

        }


        }
```

Comment: Setting the text won't update the GUI immediately. The GUI is only refreshed when a pulse occurs which can't happen while the FX thread is looping inside your `doWrite` method. If you want to do something over time on the FX thread use the [animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html); if you want to do a long running task, such as reading from an `InputStream`, use a separate thread and publish back to the FX thread as needed—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: Can you please provide the editted code for doWrite function because i m new to java and i am not getting how to solve this issue.

Comment: learning is something that only _you yourself_ can do - ready-made code wouldn't help you :) There is the api doc and many tutorials that you can start to read and understand. BTW: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.